# Direction of velocity and acceleration for a pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

The image below shows the direction between acceleration and velocity change with time. But it seems to me that the direction is not opposite. Can you please see and tell if this is correct?

[image]

Comment: Which direction is not opposite to what?  There is no reason why the acceleration needs to be in an opposite direction to the velocity.

Comment: is the picture correct?

Comment: Assuming that's a simple pendulum, it looks about right to me.

Comment: How will I understand that it is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The acceleration vector of a simple pendulum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133091/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that there are two forces acting on the pendulum:  (1) Gravity toward the earth, and (2) Tension toward the center of the circle formed by the arc that the pendulum describes.  If gravity is resolved into a vector perpendicular to the arc, and a vector tangential to the arc, the tangential component is a restoring force that returns the pendulum to dead center.

The velocity vector of the pendulum always is tangent to the arc, which is correctly indicated in the image.  The velocity vector slows near the ends of the arc, also correctly indicated in the image.  The restoring force momentarily disappears at dead center, but this does not affect the direction of the velocity vector.  This is correctly shown in the image.  The magnitude and the direction of the velocity vector seem to be correct in the image.

As the pendulum swings through its arc, the restoring force tries to bring it back to dead center.  At dead center, the pendulum has reached its equilibrium position, and velocity is constant.  That's why the acceleration vector ceases to have any direction other than toward the pivot at dead center.  At dead center, centripetal acceleration is the only component of acceleration.  This is correctly shown in the image.

At the ends of its arc, the pendulum slows and changes its direction.  As it slows, the acceleration vector grows longer in the opposite direction.  The image correctly shows this.  However, there is a centripetal as well as a tangential component of acceleration.  The image seems to show that the centripetal component of acceleration becomes a greater component of total acceleration as the pendulum approaches dead center, and a lesser component toward the ends of the arc.

The reason that the acceleration vector is directly opposite to the velocity vector only at the ends of the arc, is that the pendulum's acceleration is composed of both tangential and centripetal (vertical to the arc) components.  At the ends of the arc, when the pendulum has stopped, the centripetal force momentarily ceases.  This is where the acceleration vector has only a tangential component.  At dead center velocity is constant.  This is where the acceleration vector has only a perpendicular component.  The image seems to correctly show this.

This link explains the forces operating on a pendulum, and will enable you to determine why the velocity and the acceleration vectors act as they do in your image: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-0/Pendulum-Motion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks qualitatively correct. The acceleration and velocity are tangentially in the same direction when the pendulum is speeding up, and tangentially in opposite directions whenever the pendulum is slowing down, as it should be.

Right at the middle point, when the pendulum is momentarily moving at a constant speed, the acceleration is purely in the radial direction, as it should be for an object in circular motion at a constant speed.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity is always tangent to the arc of the pendulum, but the acceleration is not.  This is because of the centripetal acceleration, which is always directed along the pendulum toward the center of rotation.  So the acceleration has components both tangent and normal to the arc of the pendulum.  When the speed of the pendulum is increasing, the tangential velocity and the tangential component of acceleration are pointing in the same direction.  When the speed of the pendulum is decreasing, the tangential velocity and the tangential component of acceleration are pointing in opposite directions.